# How to overwrite a file in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to save files using Javascript but unfortunately I have a problem...
I can save file but my code always create a new file but I wanna create file In start and then overwrite it how can i do?

```
function get() {
         saved =1;
         const link = document.createElement("a");
         const content = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
         const file = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
         link.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
         link.download = "myfireide.html";
         link.click();
         URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
      }
```

Its always create new can u write a code which is overwrite

Comment: No, that is harmful and malicious.